How to hide specific stages in odoo17 portal users. I dont want the portal iser to see when the ticket is in In progress state when it is in the state
I have 3 stages for my support tickets . Registered, in progress, Done.
Currently the portal user can see the status of tickets according to the stage.
The thing i want to do is hide the in progress state for the portal users. When the task is in in Progress stage its still need to show the status Registerd.
When the task is completed in in progress stage the customer can see it in the done stage.
Hide the middle stage thats all.
If anyone have any idea please ping me
Everething is in the above field

Please add what you have tried till now
